# Classification of finite simple groups $G$ with $\pi(G)=\{2,3,5\}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. The set of prime divisors of $|G|$ is denoted by $\pi(G)$. I am looking for the classification of finite simple groups $G$ with $\pi(G)=\{2,3,5\}$.

Comment: We have a full [classification of all finite simple groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups). So just go through those, I guess?

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: This might be better received at MathOverflow. A) IMHO it is at research level, B) here the expectation of many voters is that a question should include some context - irrespective of whether it is a homework assignment or a question like this. Alternatively you could add some context to this, [as described in our guide for askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: Derek Holt, if you see this, please comment. Would this be ok at MO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Answered too quickly at first, improved answer now.

See this answer, which is very thorough:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67671/number-of-prime-factors-of-the-order-of-a-finite-non-abelian-simple-group

Based on the paper of Bugeaud, Cao and Mignotte, the groups you are looking for are $A_5$, $A_6$, $PSp(4,3)$ and $PSU(4,2)$.

The literature on this seems a bit confusing to me. For example, I can't understand why $PSU(4,2)$ doesn't appear in Corollary of Leon&Wales.

Also, B. C. and M. say that the case of three primes was done by Herzog, but when I chase up that paper, there is additional hypothesis.

Comment: @ Verret. Thank you so much for your concern. I don't understand why someones decided to close the post. However please if possible vote for reopen the question.